# Save video on the gallery and store the path to the video

Tags: ios, swift, video, path, photo-gallery

I have an app in which the user can record a video, this video is saved in the photo gallery, and I store the path to the video so that in the future the user could see again the video inside the app. The problem is that the method that I use I think it's giving me some kind of temporary path, and after some days, the video still in the gallery, but the path is not valid anymore and make the app crash. This is the code I'm using:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let mediaType: String = info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] as! String
    if mediaType == "public.movie" {
        let tempImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
        let pathString = tempImageURL.relativeString
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
        if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary {
            self.videoPath = pathString
            // Save the path in the DB
        } else {
            VideoManager.saveVideo(tempImageURL, onComplete: { (path) -> Void in
                self.videoPath = path
                // Save the path in the DB
            })
            var fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
            fileManager.removeItemAtPath(pathString!, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And the VideoManager.saveVideo method code is the following:

```
func saveVideo(videoURL: NSURL, onComplete:((path: String) -> Void)) {
    var assetsLibrary: ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
    assetsLibrary.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL, completionBlock: { (assetURL: NSURL!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var path: String = error == nil ? "\(assetURL)" : kEmptyString
        onComplete(path: path)
    })
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've tried with the method UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum but without success.. Any ideas?

For giving a little more information, when the video is selected from the gallery, the url I get is like the following one:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D2E8E31B-CEA0-43B0-8EF9-1820F6BDE4A9/tmp/trim.AD855155-AB78-4A16-9AA8-DF2B3F39824E.MOV
```

And when I record a new video using the camera, first I have this URL:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D2E8E31B-CEA0-43B0-8EF9-1820F6BDE4A9/tmp/capture/capturedvideo.MOV
```

and when I do writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum it returns an URL like:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=958507B5-1353-4DDC-BC07-D9CBC6126657&ext=MOV
```

Both of them work, but some days later stop working.

Comment: what do you use to access the video,  the actuel Path or you generate the path/url from the saved string.

Comment: I use the path stored in the self.videoPath variable

Comment: Ok then, when the app is relunched you recreate the path from DB saved string right?

Comment: Yes, that's it, the thing is that it works for some days, but after these days, it stops working forever

Comment: perhaps because the app is still on background, whats happen if you kill it  and relunched again.. did it still working

Comment: is it only for iOS9 ? The Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0.

Comment: no, it's not working on iOS 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally I found the solution, the thing was that you can't access directly the photo gallery with the stored url, you got to use the assetLibrary.assetForURL method, which I was missing. In the end the imagepickercontroller delegate method is like this:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let mediaType: String = info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] as! String
    if mediaType == "public.movie" {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
        if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary {
            let tempImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL!
            self.videoPath = tempImageURL.absoluteString
        } else {
            let tempImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
            VideoManager.saveVideo(tempImageURL, onComplete: { (path) -> Void in
                self.videoPath = path
            })
        }
    } 
}
```

I also was missing that when you record a video, you got to obtain the url using:

```
let tempImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
```

But when you get the video you have to do:

```
let tempImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL!
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: hey i want to store path of video, and i have used UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL, still not play video in future. any idea?