# Save video to the gallery and get the path for the video stored to Gallery

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimagepickercontroller, photokit

I want to save a video chosen from `UIImagePickerController` to the Photos album.
After that i need to fetch the URL to the saved path. I saw some pre-existing questions which answer with use of `ALAssetsLibrary` which is now deprecated.
Like : [Save video on the gallery and store the path to the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870711/save-video-on-the-gallery-and-store-the-path-to-the-video)

Can someone please guide me to use `Photo's framework` and achieve the above desired result. Kindly correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Thanks!!

Comment: please refer this one you will get an idea how to deal with PHAsset https://github.com/SanjeetVerma/UIImagePicker-PHAsset-swift/blob/master/PhotoGalleryDemo/ViewController.swift

Comment: Bro your example is nice.
But still i am not able to get the path for the video that is stored to the gallery.

Comment: You can get the path for the video in that example like let videoPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL just check in that example

Comment: that is the link to the temporary directory. I want the url for the asset stored in Gallery .

Comment: Bro this is not temporary path i am picking the video using UIimagepicker controller which gives the path of gallery not mine custom folder path after getting the path then i adding in my folder so that path is gallery assest url

Comment: bro when u use the camera to record a video then when didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called you get the temp folders location. So now u use the same location to save file to gallery. But after that were to get the link which is now accessed with the gallery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142604/discussion-between-bhupat-bheda-and-ankit-kumar-gupta).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This worked for me perfectly.

Swift 3.1 ->

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: url!)
}) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

                // After uploading we fetch the PHAsset for most recent video and then get its current location url

                let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions).lastObject 
                PHImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: fetchResult!, options: nil, resultHandler: { (avurlAsset, audioMix, dict) in
                    let newObj = avurlAsset as! AVURLAsset
                    print(newObj.url) 
                    // This is the URL we need now to access the video from gallery directly.
                    })
            }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to set the following permission in your app's plist file:

**Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description**

Provide a string that is presented to the user explaining why you are requesting the permission.

Next,

`import photos`

Then use this code to store video

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: fileURL)
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions).firstObject
            // fetchResult is your latest video PHAsset
            // To fetch latest image  replace .video with .image
        }
    }
```

To get url from PHAsset, refer to this [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887638/how-to-get-an-alasset-url-from-a-phasset)

Comment: bro where do we get the link for the saved video to gallery?

Comment: Thanks bro! Will check and get back to u

Comment: It works bro ! although with some edits for you to extract the URL out of that :) I will be posting it soon. Thanks a lot for the efforts. An upvote too.

Comment: Although i was bit messed up and we need to set ascending to true in order to use the lastObject.

Comment: It good to inform me, I'll update my answer for others. I have fetched images earlier using this but with some other filters. I updated that according to your requirement.

Comment: Please find my answer . I have updated with the results that meet the description of my question. Also upvote if you like my Q&A.
And thanks a lot for the help , you saved my day.

Comment: That is fine. Well i have updated my answer as well from lastObject to firstObject to get latest asset.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fetch the saved element (not using a sort descriptor with date order), you can do it this way:

```
var changeRequest: PHAssetChangeRequest?
var blockPlaceholder: PHObjectPlaceholder?

PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            changeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: url!)
            blockPlaceholder = changeRequest?.placeholderForCreatedAsset
}) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                guard let placeholder = blockPlaceholder else {
                    return
                }
                let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                let fetchResult:PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeholder.localIdentifier], options: fetchOptions)
                if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject {
                    //here you have the PHAsset
                } 
            }
}
```

Comment: Will have a look at this too and update if it acts more appropriately.

Comment: In our case it fails in iOS 13 someone else did face the same problem? it gives  the PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo

Answer (score 1):

Try like this!

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
if mediaType.isEqualToString(kUTTypeMovie as NSString as String) || mediaType.isEqualToString(kUTTypeVideo as NSString as String){
    let videoPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL // Path of video Url
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
    let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(videoPath)
    let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest?.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset)
            albumChangeRequest!.addAssets([assetPlaceholder!])
       }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                    NSLog("Adding video to Library ->%@", (success ? "Success" : "Error"))
                    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer for Objective-C

Code Sample:

```
 [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlOfFile]];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                      if (success)
                                      {
                                          PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc]init];
                                          fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:false]];
                                          PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:fetchOptions];
                                          PHAsset *lastAsset = [fetchResult lastObject];
                                          [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:lastAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
                                              //here's the url to the file
                                              NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];


                                      }else{
                                          NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                                      }
                                  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this by creating extension of the URL Class

```
extension URL {

    func saveVideo( success:@escaping (Bool,URL?)->()){


        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: URLRequest(url: self)) { (url, response, error) in

            let mgr = FileManager.default

            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]


            let destination = URL(fileURLWithPath: String(format: "%@/%@", documentsPath, "video.mp4"))


            try? mgr.moveItem(atPath: /url?.path, toPath: /destination.path)

            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: destination)
            }) { completed, error in
                if completed {
                    print("Video is saved!")
                    success(true,destination)
                }
                if error != nil{
                    success(false,nil)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

when you want to save and play you can use this in ViewController as

```
guard let urlToDownload = URL(string: videoURLStringToDownload) else { return }

  urlToDownload.saveVideo(success: { (isSaved,url) in           
    guard let videoURL = url, isSaved else { return }

        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
          let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
           playerViewController.player = player
          self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                            playerViewController.player?.play()
          }
    })
```

import **AVKit** for playing videos through AVPlayerViewController

import **Photos** and **PhotosUI** for saving Video with PHAsset.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are saving the video to documents directory first then creating the save request to gallery. To avoid memory consumption of app only I wanted to save it gallery and then refer the video from there.

Comment: Okay!!! for that you can refer to this [class](https://github.com/zakkhoyt/PHAsset-Utility) for saving and retrieving directly from Albums.